# Spring Security in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, oauth2, security, passwordencoder

Estoy trabajando para desarrollar Spring Security en Spring 3.2.1, y empece con el auth-server con arquitectura de microservicios, donde con esta configuracion actual obtengo el Authorization Code y de ahi, el token, pero teniendo la configuracion actual, no puedo implementar el passwordEncoder(), ya que al realizarlo, siempre me tira un INVALID_GRANT o BAD_CREDENTIALS, porque no me dejara? (y eso que saco el {noop}. No pude encontrar nada similar, esta es una configuracion de la [docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html).

**auth-server Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
@Slf4j
public class OAuthUserController {

    //login: http://127.0.0.1:8090/ms-users/oauth2/authorization/frontend-app

    @GetMapping("/authorized")
    public Map<String, String> authorized(@RequestParam String code) {
        log.info("Calling authorized with {}", code);
        return Collections.singletonMap("code", code);
    }

}
```

**auth-server SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

//    @Autowired
//    private UserService userService;
//
//    @Bean
//    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
//        return username -> {
//            User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
//            if (user == null) {
//                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " does not exists");
//            }
//            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles()
//                    .stream()
//                    .map(rol -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol.getName()))
//                    .peek(authority -> log.info("rol: " + authority.getAuthority()))
//                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
//
//            log.info("username: " + username + "----------------------------------");
//            return new UserOauth(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
//                    false, true, true, true, authorities);
//        };
//    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsManager() {
        UserDetails susan = User.builder()
                .username("susan")
                .password("{noop}12345")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(susan);
    }

//    @Bean
//    public UserDetailsService userDetailsManager() {
//        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
//        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("susan")
//                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("12345")).authorities("read")
//                .build();
//        userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
//        return userDetailsManager;
//    }

    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("frontend-app")
                .clientSecret("{noop}12345")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:9000/login/oauth2/code/frontend-app")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:9000/authorized")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:9000/logout")
                .scope("read")
                .scope("write")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

}
```

**y el ms-users (microservicio de usuarios):**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authHttp) -> authHttp
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/authorized").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").hasAnyAuthority("SCOPE_read", "SCOPE_write")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/").hasAuthority("SCOPE_write")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2Login(login -> login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/frontend-app"))
                .oauth2Client(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando intentas autenticarte con una contraseña en texto plano y Spring Security espera una contraseña codificada, es probable que ocurra un error de credenciales no válidas (INVALID_GRANT o BAD_CREDENTIALS). En lugar de usar contraseñas en texto plano en tu configuración, deberías codificarlas usando BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no estas unando Bcrypt pero piensas usarlo despues define tu Password encoder con ambos

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = Map.of(
            BCRYPT_ENCODER_STRATEGY_NAME, new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCRYPT_STRENGTH),
            "noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance()
    );
    return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(BCRYPT_ENCODER_STRATEGY_NAME, encoders);
}
```

Aqui te dejo el link de un repo donde esta la configuracion de un autorization server:
https://github.com/rbautisf/spring-auth-server

y los videos donde se configuran:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfB-Jrd1jeK7H96hTWkgC9g

Si te ayuda un like no estaria mal.